# Determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider  $ a_n = (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)$
and  $ b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{a_k}\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$ Then which of the following is true:

a.) $\lim_{n \to \infty } b_n = 0$
b.) $\lim\sup_{n \to \infty } b_n > \frac{1}{2}$ 
c.) $\lim\inf_{n \to \infty } b_n < -\frac{1}{2}$ 
d.) $0\le\lim\inf_{n \to \infty } b_n \le \lim\sup_{n \to \infty } b_n \le \frac{1}{2}$

My attempt:

I wrote a few terms for $b_n$ 
$ b_1 = -1/2+ 1$
$ b_2 = -1/2+ 1 + (1/2 - 1/2) = -1/2+1$
$ b_3 = 1-1/2+(-1/2+1/3) = 1/3$
$ b_4 = 1-1/2+(-1/2+1/3) +(1/2 - 1/4) = 1-1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4$
$ b_5 = 1/3 - 1/4 - 1/5$ 
So I was able to discover the following pattern
$$ b_n = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+2}} =1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}-\cdots \,\,\, n \,\, is\,\, even$$
$$ b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+2}}= \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}-\cdots \,\,\, n \,\, is\,\, odd  $$

If we look at the subsequence $b_{2n}$ i.e.
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } b_{2n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}-\cdots = \ln(1+1) = 0.693 $$
As it is the expansion of ln(1+1).
Similaryly for $b_{2n - 1}$ we have,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } b_{2n - 1} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \cdots \right) - \frac{1}{2} = \ln(1+1) - \frac{1}{2} = 0.193 $$

$\therefore \lim\sup_{n \to \infty } b_n = 0.693$ and $ \lim\inf_{n \to \infty } b_n = 0.193 $

So option b.) should be the correct option.

Now, I got the answer right but the solution that was provided for this problem suggested that $b_n$ converges to $\ln2$. So I'm unsure if my solution is correct.

Comment: Since $\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n<\log 2$, you cannot have $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\log 2$.

Comment: $(b_n)$ does not converge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition, Let $B_n=\{b_n, b_{n+1},\dots \}, s_n=\sup B_n, i_n=\inf B_n$, and

$$b_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$

where the first part equals either $-\frac12$ or $0$, depends on the index $n$ being odd or even, the second part converges to $\ln 2\approx0.693$. Depending on the index $n$ being odd or even, the second partial sum will oscillate around $\ln 2\approx0.693$, so we can get,

$$\begin{align}\limsup b_n&=\lim s_n=0+\ln2>\frac12\\
\\
0<\liminf b_n&=\lim i_n=-\frac12+\ln2<\frac12\end{align}$$